# iOS7 translucent and live app icons

Tags: icons, ios7

It it possible to make app icons live (such as Clock icon) or be translucent (such as folders icons)? 
Can't find any official information about it, only ios7 commercials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of I Believe that there is no translucent or live capability for third party applications when it comes to the home screen unfortunately. But you can make various elements within your application translucent.